# Переодически выключается WiFi на Kali Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, tp-link, rtl

У меня есть WiFi - адаптер TP-Link AC1200 Realtek rtl8812au и я установил драйвер https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au Но периодически выключается WiFi. Не отключается от точки доступа, просто пропадает интернет. Прошу помочь, надуюсь кто-нибудь знает как то решить.

P.S: Дело в том, что я переустановил систему и до этого действия, на этом же адаптере с этим драйвером и все было хорошо

Вывод: `uname -a`

```
Linux USER 4.18.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.20-2kali2 (2018-11-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Чем не устроил драйвер из дистрибутива?

Comment: @0andriy Его нет)

Comment: Говорят, есть: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?40179-Live-USB-kernel-version-is-wrong-so-rtl8812au-driver-install-breaks

Comment: @0andriy Я просто переустановил linux и все заработало

Comment: Да драйвер в дебайне битый, все дистрибутивы задело. Надо было по кабелю апдейт скачать.

Comment: В драйвере был баг, он и выключался. Было такое же, но обошелся без переустановки системы. По вашей ссылке на GitHub посмотрите, там есть о нём упоминание.